# How to render HTML template via flask as a response to POST request made in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, flask

I am making an AJAX request via JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/available_data',
            type: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'X-CSRFToken': csrf_token
            },
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(response) {
              
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
              console.log(xhr)
              console.log(status)
              console.log(error)
            }
          });
```

As a response to this POST request made by the client, I want to render an HTML template via flask:

```
if request.is_json:
       return render_template('my_template')
```

I have tried making a POST request like this via javascript:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "/available_data");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', csrf_token);
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

But it still does not let me directly render a html template via flask

Comment: Can you add some more detail please?  What does "it still does not let me directly render a html template" mean exactly?  Do you get an error, or does something else unexpected happen?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why not use that for the POST request rather than the `XMLHttpRequest`? Please share a [mcve] with your endpoint.